# Synonyms causing an expensive plan

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, synonym, sql-execution-plan

I had the following problem with our Oracle 11 database and although there's a fix,
I want to understand why its reacting this way.

We have two schemas: a "dev" schema which contains all the tables, views, plsql, ... and
a "app" schema which contains synonyms to the dev-objects, i.e. statements don't contain
schema names.

A dev-view references tables (`select * from a a1 -> b -> a a2 union select * from c`)
in which there's a common column which is used for the selection, i.e. the selection
predicate is pushed into table "a" (300k rows) and "b" (90k rows) selection via seperate
index access, resulting in a very performant plan.

dev-fun is a deterministic, parallel function which simply does some string manipulation
without further database access.

The selection on the view looks like: `select * from view where common-column = fun(string)`
This works as expected on the dev schema, but if this is executed on the app schema,
the plan becomes relatively very expensive, i.e. the result of `fun(string)` is not pushed down,
but the tables are hash joined and the result is scanned for the element.

Still in the app schema, when I replace `fun(string)` with the function-result the plan becomes
cheap again.

To solve the problem, I duplicated the view in the app schema instead of referencing it via
a synonym, but in case of view/table-changes that means a potential source of defect, as we
normally don't check the app schema ...
The call to the function is still via the synonym and the view was duplicated as-is, i.e. it
accesses the synonyms for the underlying tables ... and the plan is the same as if it was executed
on the dev schema.

Apart of having selection grants on all underlying tables, I've also tried granting "query rewrite", "references" on the tables and "references" on the view. Furthermore I've tried the authid-options on the function. I have to admit, that I haven't yet checked for [row-level security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/781224/why-would-an-oracle-synonym-return-a-different-number-of-rows-to-the-underlying), but we are not using them.

What else can I check for?

The oracle version is 11.0.2.2. Opening a oracle-ticket would be only a theoretical option,
as we don't have direct support access and the layer in-between is even more frustrating as
living with the maintaining issue.

I know that typically a explain-plan would be helpful, but lets try it first without it, as
I suspect the problem somewhere else.

Update (14.10.2013):

- Hinting to use nested loops doesn't work.
- function based index aren't used.

Indexed access: `select * from v_vt_betreuer where vtid = 11803056;`

[image]

Hashed access: `select * from v_vt_betreuer where vtid =  VTNRVOLL_TO_VTID(11803056);`

[image]

Copied view: i.e. when the view is copied into the app schema

`select * from v_vt_betreuer where vtid =  VTNRVOLL_TO_VTID(11803056);`

[image]

Comment: Let me see if I understood: You have a view that joins 2 tables by one field. You have an alias to this table. You have a deterministic function. If you query the view by the result of the function in its own schema the plan takes the indexes but if you query the same view by the alias it does not. Is it?

Comment: Yes. The first part of the union is a one-level hierarchical join of table "a" (twice) with an association table "b". The join attribute differs from the common attribute (letz call it vtid). the other table of the union is very small. If the alias is used with a literal the indexes are used again.

Comment: Sorry the last comment was partly wrong. The common attribute is used in the join - something like ˋselect a1.vtid, a2.* from agency a1 join agency_employee b on (b.vtid = a1.vtid) join agency a2 on (a2.vtid = b.employee_vtid)ˋ

Comment: You say that the common attribute differs from the join attribute and you're searching by the common attribute, which therefore is in the view only once. Is the function `func(string)` used on a variable/parameter or on another field?

Comment: @Y.Ecarri Regarding the common attribute, I've corrected that comment before. The function is used via a bind-parameter, but the same happens when the function is used with a literal. I think 11g supports plsql function inlin(e)ing used by other plsql, does this also apply to sql?

Answer (score 1):

Try creating an index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX func_index ON agency(fun(common_column))
```

This is called a function based index.

My guess is that this type of queries:

```
select a1.vtid, a2.* 
from agency a1 join agency_employee b on (b.vtid = a1.vtid)
join agency a2 on (a2.vtid = b.employee_vtid)
```

is causing the query optimizer to do this:

```
select a1.vtid, a2.* 
from agency a1 join agency_employee b on (func(b.vtid) = func(a1.vtid))
join agency a2 on (func(a2.vtid) = func(b.employee_vtid))
```

http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_function_based_index_2.html
http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/8i/function-based-indexes.php

If this approach does not help, check if you have ROW LEVEL SECURITY:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17609/tdpsg_ols.htm
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/apdvcntx.htm#i1007410

Comment: I'm curious if this will change the plan, as the function is not used in the join ... but of course the optimizer is sometimes something magical ... I'll give an update tomorrow when I'm back at work ...

Comment: sorry, this approach didn't work. After I've added the function based index (create index abe_vertreter on webcc_vertreter(VTNRVOLL_TO_VTID(vtid)); create index abe_vertreter2 on webcc_vt_betreuer(VTNRVOLL_TO_VTID(vtid));) ... the explain plan still stayed the same. If you a curious, I've attached the plans in the question.

Comment: check if you have row level security. In some cases it's posible to set a view so that certain users don't see the whole table. That could cause different executin plans.

Comment: As mentioned in my question, we don't use row level security. I've just checked again with `SELECT * FROM dba_policies` that there aren't any policies for the two schemes

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are NOT using actual function in schema NPS_WEBCC, but a synonym to a function in schema NPS_WEBCC_DEV?

Condition can't be pushed if DEV schema is not allowed to access objects in APP schema.
You must grant permission for synonym to DEV schema, because view is in DEV schema. That is why it starts working when you copy view into APP schema.

Another problem may occur if you use extended statistics in DEV schema based on DEV function, but that needs to be sorted out after the permissions problem.

You can verify it by checking explain plans of following queries. They shall give optimized result:

```
-- q1
-- "v_vt_betreuer" is a synonym in app schema to a view in dev schema 
select * from v_vt_betreuer where vtid = NPS_WEBCC_DEV.VTNRVOLL_TO_VTID(11803056);

-- q2
select * from NPS_WEBCC_DEV.v_vt_betreuer where vtid=NPS_WEBCC_DEV.VTNRVOLL_TO_VTID(11803056);
```

*UPD*
According to additional investigation most likely problem happens because MERGE grant is missing on the view. It must be granted for the view and all sub-views that are used inside it.

```
GRANT MERGE VIEW ON v_vt_betreuer TO NPS_WEBCC;
```

Comment: I'm sure about using a synonym in nps_webcc which access the function in nps_webcc_dev. Not sure if granting on synonyms is possible, but I'll try it on Monday. Regarding the extended statistics, I don't think we use histograms on these, but also will check for it. Thank you for bearing with me.

Comment: Both selects result in the expensive plan. Regarding the extended statistics, I don't want to provide too much internals (i.e. screenshots) of the tables, but as you can see from the screenshots above, the common column (vtid) has a unique-index-scan access, but there's no histogram on vtid in the two joined tables. I'll give it a shot with a histogram tomorrow ...

Comment: **Both selects result in the expensive plan**
This is something I wouldn't expect for q2. Can you check q2 execution plan when logged in under DEV schema? I assume this is the one to begin with and that it has to be cheap for sure. If q2 is cheap under DEV and expensive under APP, it has to do something with grants and policies.

Comment: q2 is cheap under DEV. currently app has only the select-right on the view and the underlying tables. Also already stated in my question, that I've played around with "rewrite" and "references" grants, which grants might be helpful?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have execute grants on functions, otherwise it wouldn't be working at all. You must check MERGE grant on the view. It is the grant that will allow your app schema to push condition inside the view.
**GRANT MERGE VIEW ON  v_vt_betreuer TO NPS_WEBCC;**

of course, this shall be allowed for all internal views of "v_vt_betreuer"